# nftables rule for wireguard

Tags: nftables

I used to have an iptables rule that would allow wireguard traffic to pass:

from ferm:

```
proto udp dport 51820 mod owner ! uid-owner 0-4294967294 mod conntrack     ctstate (NEW) ACCEPT;
```

using the translation tool this became:

```
 udp dport 51820 meta skuid != 0-4294967294 ct state new accept
```

yet when I look at the counters and logged packets this rule isn't being hit.

How to do this using nftables?

Comment: You should give the whole ruleset rather than an isolated rule without context.

Comment: Well that rule is being missed because there is a log for all packets after it

Comment: Yeah nfttables from the kernel. no go.

Comment: Can't figure this out without the context (network settings, wireguard settings, full nftables ruleset).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how do you do something like this:
https://superuser.com/questions/1579741/iptables-rule-for-filtering-wireguard-packets
in nftables then you cannot add a rule that excludes the entire 32 bit range as you would in iptables.

in nftables you need two rules. The first to drop the entire 32 bit uid range and a second to accept port 51820 (as there is no uid).

```
chain wireguard_enable {
        udp dport 51820 meta skuid { 0-4294967294 } ct state new drop
        udp dport 51820 ct state new accept

}
```